# Reading C Input with skipping commas and columns

Tags: c, input, filereader, scanf, file-read

I am new to C and i wanted to do File Read operations.
Here i have input.txt which contains :

```
(g1,0.95) (g2,0.30) (m3,0.25) (t4,0.12) (s5,0.24)
(m0,0.85) (m1,0.40) (m2,0.25) (m3,0.85) (m4,0.5) (m5,0.10)
```

now, i wanted to save k1,k2,k3 etc in array keys[10] and the 0.15,0.10,0.05 in the array values[10]

is there any way to skip the first "(", ignore "," and " " without specifying one by one? i tried to search for tutorials and i heard that i can read several characters before and after with it, but i think i misled them. Can somebody show me how to achieve this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define HEIGHT 2
#define WIDTH  6

int main(void)
{
     FILE *myfile;
     char nothing[100];
     char leaf[2];
     float value;

     char keys[10];
     float values[10];

     int i;
     int j;
     int counter=0;

     myfile=fopen("input.txt", "r");

     for(i = 0; i < HEIGHT; i++)
     { 
         for (j = 0 ; j < WIDTH; j++)
         { 
             fscanf(myfile,"%1[^(],%s[^,],%4f[^)]",nothing,leaf,value);
             printf("(%s,%f)\n",leaf,value);
             keys[counter]=leaf;
             values[counter]=value;
             counter++;
         }
         printf("\n");
     }

     fclose(myfile);

 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I would do it:

```
int main( void )
{
    // open the file
    FILE *fp;
    if ( (fp = fopen("test.txt", "r")) == NULL )
        exit( 1 );

    // declare the arrays
    char keys[10][32];
    float values[10];

    // load them up
    int i;
    for ( i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
        if ( fscanf( fp, " ( %31[^ ,] ,%f )", keys[i], &values[i] ) != 2 )
            break;
    int count = i;

    // print them out
    printf( "%d\n", count );
    for ( i = 0; i < count; i++ )
        printf( "%s %.2f\n", keys[i], values[i] );

    // close the file
    fclose( fp );
}
```

The key is the format specifier for the `scanf` which consists of 5 elements.
Note that I'm using underscores to show where the spaces are

```
_(_      skips whitespace, matches the opening parenthesis, skips whitespace
%31[^_,] reads at most 31 characters, stopping on a space or a comma
_,       skips whitespace, matches the comma
%f       reads a floating point value
_)       skips whitespace, matches the closing parenthesis
```

Comment: wow !
thank you so much for helping. But i have a small question here: 
so the %31 (  or any number you want ) here is reading a character value? so that means i can change 31 to any numbers i want right?

and also, the values in [^ ,], this means its skipping " " and "," in a one notation is it?

Comment: @KevinYan The `%31` must be one less than the size of the array to avoid buffer overflow. For example, since I reserved 32 bytes for each string with the array declaration `keys[10][32]`, then I need to tell `scanf` not to write more than 31 bytes, plus the null terminator. You can use any length, doesn't have to be 32. The conversion `[^ ,]` means "read a string consisting of any characters until a space or comma is found".

Comment: @ChristopherSchneider Because regex is not part of the C language. You're welcome to post your own answer recommending and demonstrating the use of a library that provides regex capability in a C program.

Comment: Was not aware of that. There's nothing in ANSI C, but there is regex in POSIX, so I imagine it's pretty common.
http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/regcomp.3.html
A world without regex is not a place I want to live.

Comment: *"I imagine it's pretty common."* Doubtful, the `fscanf` is one line of code, and you propose to replace it with how many lines of (obscure, non-portable) code?